# Better usage of _.each by using _.reduce

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the need to extract data form an existing array, to filter only year and `reference_id` for every item where quantity is `> 0`.

My `sample_array` contains this data :

```
var sample_array = [{
    'reference_id': 1,
    'products': [{
        year: 1,
        quantity: 0
    }, {
        year: 2009,
        quantity: 5
    }]
}, {
    'reference_id': 2,
    'products': [{
        year: 2009,
        quantity: 0
    }]
}, {
    'reference_id': 3,
    'products': [{
        year: 1,
        quantity: 0
    }, {
        year: 2009,
        quantity: 5
    }]
}, {
    'reference_id': 4,
    'products': [{
        year: 2014,
        quantity: 10
    }, {
        year: 2015,
        quantity: 6
    }]
}];
```

To let me extract the way I need my data, I used twice `_.each` (I'm still using *underscore.js* on few projects) to filter first, then to rebuild an array with the `year` and the `reference_id`.

```
var references = [];

_.each(sample_array, function(reference) {
    reference_products = _.filter(reference.products, function(data) {
        return data.quantity > 0;
    });
    if (!_.isEmpty(reference_products))
        _.each(reference_products, function(product) {
            references.push({
                'reference_id': reference.reference_id,
                'year': product.year
            });
        });
});
```

It works without any problems, but I think it may exists a more elegant way to build my array references, buy using `_.reduce` but I didn't found the way to achieve it.

Expected results would be for `console.log(references)`:

```
[{
    reference_id: 1
    year: 2009
} {
    reference_id: 3
    year: 2009
} {
    reference_id: 4
    year: 2014
} {
    reference_id: 4
    year: 2015
}]
```

Any tips ?

Comment: "I think it may exists a more elegant way to build my array references, buy using _.reduce but I didn't found the way to achieve it." -- how exactly did you try to achieve it?

Comment: `_.reduce()` is just an `_.each()` that returns something on each step which is passed into the next step.

Comment: You don’t need ‘.reduce()’ but ‘.map()’.

Answer (score 3):

`reduce` will complicate the code unnecessarily, as you’ll have to manually collect the results. Instead, you can express this by `map`ping over the array to create an intermediate array with only the desired values, then flattening it:

```
var sample_array = [{
  'reference_id': 1,
  'products': [{
    year: 1,
    quantity: 0
  }, {
    year: 2009,
    quantity: 5
  }]
}, {
  'reference_id': 2,
  'products': [{
    year: 2009,
    quantity: 0
  }]
}, {
  'reference_id': 3,
  'products': [{
    year: 1,
    quantity: 0
  }, {
    year: 2009,
    quantity: 5
  }]
}, {
  'reference_id': 4,
  'products': [{
    year: 2014,
    quantity: 10
  }, {
    year: 2015,
    quantity: 6
  }]
}];

const combined = _.map(
  sample_array,
  (e) =>                        // for each first-level element...
    _.chain(e.products)         // look at its `products` array...
    .filter((p) => p.quantity > 0) // keeping only those with a quantity > 0
    .map((p) => {                  // and now return the result of mapping over that array of products
      return {
        reference_id: e.reference_id,
        year: p.year
      };
    })
    .value());

console.log(combined);

// the above value is an array of arrays (one per first-level
// element), so we need to flatten it
const references = _.flatten(combined, true);

console.log(references);
```

(I used [`_.chain`](https://underscorejs.org/#chaining) inside the transformation function to make the flow clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

This is my alternative way to solve the issue using `reduce`, `filter` and `map`.

```js
const references = [{
    'reference_id': 1,
    'products': [{
        year: 1,
        quantity: 0
    }, {
        year: 2009,
        quantity: 5
    }]
}, {
    'reference_id': 2,
    'products': [{
        year: 2009,
        quantity: 0
    }]
}, {
    'reference_id': 3,
    'products': [{
        year: 1,
        quantity: 0
    }, {
        year: 2009,
        quantity: 5
    }]
}, {
    'reference_id': 4,
    'products': [{
        year: 2014,
        quantity: 10
    }, {
        year: 2015,
        quantity: 6
    }]
}];

const result = references.reduce((acc, reference) => {
  const { reference_id, products } = reference;
  const productsWithQuantity = products.filter(product => product.quantity > 0);
  const productsWithReference = productsWithQuantity.map(product => ({ reference_id: reference_id, year: product.year}));
  
  return [...acc, ...productsWithReference];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```